# UPPY: How to get json data returned from failed upload

Tags: javascript

I am using Uppy javascript library with xhr plugin to upload files.
How do I get the response data on a upload error?  The below does not provide the json returned from my service.  Documentation [here](https://uppy.io/docs/xhr-upload/)

```
uppy.on('upload-error', function (file, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: what service are you using?

Comment: From a quick glance the `getResponseError` function might be what you're looking for?
https://uppy.io/docs/xhr-upload/#getResponseError-responseText-response

Comment: @Thornkey Yes, I see that but I don't know how to implement it in code.  Any idea?

Comment: @cegfault I wrote my own REST service and it works fine.  I can get the response in Fiddler without issue.  Just don't understand how to get the response, their documentation doesn't show a good example of how to implement in javascript.

Comment: I feel ya - the docs could do with some more sample code. I feel like replacing the `console.log` with `uppy.getResponseData (responseText, response) {
// do stuff
}` might be what you're looking for? This is the first time i've seen Uppy before as a library so I might not be best placed to help you haha

Comment: Maybe one of the contributors will respond.  Thx

Answer (score 2):

It can be passed as an option for XHR Upload plugin:

```
const XHRUpload = require('@uppy/xhr-upload')

uppy.use(XHRUpload, {
    endpoint: 'http://my-website.org/upload',
    getResponseError (responseText, response) {
        return new Error(JSON.parse(responseText).message)
    }
})
```

Same goes for getResponseData():

```
const XHRUpload = require('@uppy/xhr-upload')

uppy.use(XHRUpload, {
    endpoint: 'http://my-website.org/upload',
    getResponseData (responseText, response) {
        return {
            url: responseText.match(/<Location>(.*?)<\/Location>/)[1]
        }
    }
})
```

Here we are only showing the error message from the JSON response in the getResponseError() method but you can of course do pretty much anything with the response.

Answer (score 0):

uppy takes three values in callback for `upload-error` event. So to get the status you can do something like this

```js
  uppy.on('upload-error', (file, error, response) => {
    const { name } = file;
    message.error(`Failed in uploading ${name}`);
    if (response.status === 413) {
      message.warning('Please check the file size');
    }
  });
```